# WinForms: can a menu click handler determine which edit control on the form had focus immediately preceding the click?

Tags: winforms, lostfocus

WinForms.

Let's say we have a grid on the form with some cell editors (checkboxes, radio button groups). The form has a file menu.  File -> Save.   User visits a few cells in the grid, and clicks a checkbox in a cell, and, without touching anything else with the mouse and without touching the Tab key, clicks on the File menu and then clicks Save.

Inside the Save menuitem click handler, is it possible to determine which checkbox in the grid had focus immediately prior?  That checkbox won't have lostfocus yet because a menu choice doesn't cause its lostfocus event to fire.

Comment: So if i understand, your question is how to determine the checkbox focused in the grid???

Comment: @Precious Tijesunimi: checkbox, or radiobutton group, or similar editor. But yes, that is my question.

Comment: There's a lot of "if" in that description...sounds flimsy.  Depends on what grid.  Stock DataGridView or someone's custom job?  If it allows you to access the cell editor(s), then probably, but that will be very control-specific access.  This isn't a general WinForms question, it's a question specific to some grid control.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: are you CERTAIN that this is not general WinForms behavior? In my experience, clicking on a menu or on a form button does not cause the previously focused control to lose focus.

Comment: You miss my point.  Regardless of what does or doesn't lose focus, you have to drill into the grid control to get to the editor.  I'm betting it won't be easy.  That isn't a control that the Form is going to know about, it's embedded in your grid.